# Windows IIS sessoin timeout settings while using NTLM (Windows 10)

Tags: iis, ntlm

Using IIS server with NTLM authentication. Where can I modify the session timeout settings?.

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1665958.aspx?ASP+NET+Windows+Authentication+timeout+

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is almost impossible to control the lifetime of your NTLM ticket from server side.So windows authentication should be implemented in a trusted environment.

I think the only way to log out windows authentication is clean cache in server side and re-open web browser.

If you need kind of authentication that ticket timeout can be controlled all the time, you could use custom form authentication instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs